# Evaluate Pandas DataFrame against two string values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame "table" that contains a column called "OPINION", filled with string values. I would like to create a new column called "cond5" that is filled with TRUE for every row where "OPINION" is either "buy" or "neutral".

I have tried

```
table["cond5"]= table.OPINION == "buy" or table.OPINION == "neutral"
```

which gives me an error, and

```
table["cond5"]= table.OPINION.all() in ("buy", "neutral")
```

which returns FALSE for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And as Ed Chum points out, you could use the [`isin` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
table['cond5'] = table['OPINION'].isin(['buy', 'neutral'])
```

`isin` checks for exact equality. Perhaps that would be **easiest and most readable**.

---

To fix

```
table["cond5"] = table.OPINION == "buy" or table.OPINION == "neutral"
```

use

```
table["cond5"] = (table['OPINION'] == "buy") | (table['OPINION'] == "neutral")
```

The parentheses are necessary because `|` has [higher precedence (binding power)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`.

`x or y` requires `x` and `y` to be booleans.

```
(table['OPINION'] == "buy") or (table['OPINION'] == "neutral")
```

raises an error since [Series can no be reduced to a single boolean value](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

So instead use the logical-or operator `|`, which takes the `or` of the values in the Series element-wise.

---

Another alternative is

```
import numpy as np
table["cond5"] = np.logical_or.reduce([(table['OPINION'] == val) for val in ('buy', 'neutral')])
```

which might be useful if `('buy', 'neutral')` were a longer tuple.

---

Yet another option is to use Pandas' [vectorized string method, `str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern):

```
table["cond5"] = table['OPINION'].str.contains(r'buy|neutral')
```

`str.contains` performs a regex search for the pattern `r'buy|neutral'` in a Cythonized loop for each item in `table['OPINION']`.

---

Now how to decide which one to use? Here is a timeit benchmark using [IPython](http://ipython.org/):

```
In [10]: table = pd.DataFrame({'OPINION':np.random.choice(['buy','neutral','sell',''], size=10**6)})

In [11]: %timeit (table['OPINION'] == "buy") | (table['OPINION'] == "neutral")
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit np.logical_or.reduce([(table['OPINION'] == val) for val in ('buy', 'neutral')])
1 loops, best of 3: 204 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit table['OPINION'].str.contains(r'buy|neutral')
1 loops, best of 3: 474 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit table['OPINION'].isin(['buy', 'neutral'])
10 loops, best of 3: 40 ms per loop
```

So it looks like **`isin` is fastest**.

Comment: Another method is `table['OPINION'].isin(['buy', 'neutral'])`